I made _layouts folder in my root directory to remove "subscribe via RSS" which appears in minima template. But if I add a new post, it doesn't update
I wanted to remove "Subscribe via RSS" from my home page while using minima theme in Jekyll. I read on the internet that make a _layouts folder in the root directory and then make home.html file and remove "Subscribe via RSS". It worked. But now if I add a new post in _posts, it doesn't automatically get updated in my home.html. How do I solve this?
If I don't have a _layouts folder and I simply keep the index.html in _sites folder, it updates my home page automatically when I add a post, but the problem here is that "Subscribe via RSS" still remains.

I changed my main tag in home.html and the problem got solved.


 <main class="page-content" aria-label="Content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="home">
        <h2 class="post-list-heading">Posts</h2>
        <ul class="post-list">
          {% for post in site.posts %}
            <li>
              <span class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</span>
              <h3>
                <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">
                  {{ post.title }}
                </a>
              </h3>
            </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>



I hope this helped.
